# Do addEventListener add or set?

Tags: javascript, dom-events

Can *addEventListener* be used to add several functions to the same event on same target? Or does another *addEventListener* replace a previous setting?

I ask because I want the code from this site and the question is if it would be much easier done by *addEventListener*, or is it a similar solution? I know **window.onload = f** and **addEventListener("load", f)** is almost the same, but not sure on this details. Do I need that code? Asking the other way: Why do they not use *addEventListener* if it can add?..

http://webreference.com/programming/javascript/onloads/index-2.html

```
function addLoadEvent(func) { 
  var oldonload = window.onload; 
  if (typeof window.onload != 'function') { 
    window.onload = func; 
  } else { 
    window.onload = function() { 
      if (oldonload) { 
        oldonload(); 
      } 
      func(); 
    } 
  } 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add as many listeners of a particular type as you want with `addEventListener`:

```js
div.addEventListener('click', () => console.log('listener 1'));
div.addEventListener('click', () => console.log('listener 2'));
```

```html
<div id="div">click me</div>
```

In contrast, when you assign to an `on-` event property, if there was something that had been assigned to that property before, it will be lost, and only the last one assigned to it will run:

```js
div.onclick = () => console.log('listener 1');
div.onclick = () => console.log('listener 2');
```

```html
<div id="div">click me</div>
```

So, in general, it's best to use `addEventListener` to make sure that your script doesn't overwrite another's listener, and to make sure that your listener doesn't get overwritten either.

The code in the question is quite strange - yes, they should be using `addEventListener` instead.

Comment: Good answer! Big difference I not have perceived. So div.onclick is a removeEventListener too?

Comment: Kind of - `onclick` is actually a property with a *getter* and a *setter*. When you assign to `.onclick`, an internal function runs which removes the listener previously assigned by `onclick`.

Comment: I see some elegance in .onclick - Two in one

Comment: How is example two made by removeEventListener? Would you add a third example to clarify difference if possible, would be interesting?

Comment: The code that does that is *native code*, unfortunately, and can't be shown directly: see `Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(HTMLElement.prototype, 'onclick')`. But, it acts just as I commented - when you assign to it, the native setter function runs, and basically calls `removeEventListener` with whatever listener the setter was previously called with.

Answer (score 0):

> Can addEventListener be used to add several functions to the same event on the same target?

Yes

> Or does another addEventListener replace a previous setting?

No

> Why do they not use addEventListener if it can add?

Probably because of unknowledge on `addEventListener` capabilities? or maybe for illustrating some situations.